# Different opacity for UILabel and the text of the UILabel

Tags: uilabel, xcode4.3

I have a `UILabel` whose opacity has been changed to blank by using `[UIColor clearColor]`
I now want to change the opacity of the text within the label to the full possible level.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code to change the opacity of `UILabel` text

```
[headerLabel setAlpha:0.5];
```

Happy coding..:)